# Error: Failed to resolve "AuthenticationServices.ASWebAuthenticationSession" reference from "Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-devops

We're using **Azure DevOps** to build our **Xamarin Forms** mobile app. This has been working without any problems for weeks now. For some reason I am now getting the following error when we build the iOS project:

**MT2002: Failed to resolve "AuthenticationServices.ASWebAuthenticationSession" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065"**

The Android and shared project are working perfectly. This is only a problem with the iOS project.

I haven't changed or updated *Xamarin.iOS* in any way whatsoever, so cannot understand why I am now getting this error.

I am using *Visual Studio 2017 15.8.1* if that makes any difference.

I suspect the error first occurred after adding a reference to Microsoft.Identity.Client preview in the shared project. Is there an issue with this reference and Xamarin.iOS on Azure DevOps?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue? Other than downgrading ?

Comment: In my particular case I have downgraded. The issue has stil not been resolved by Microsoft.

Comment: I manage to fix this issue. Now I can run with the latest Identity Client lib. Please find the solution here.https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/852

Comment: @RakeshRNair Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issues, and had to downgrade to version 2.1.0-preview.
2.2.0, 2.2.1 and 2.3.0 give the same error.

Comment: That confirms my suspicions. I'll have to downgrade too. Thanks.

Comment: Version 2.3.1-preview was released few days ago and still does not work. Depending on your project/company/client, you can set up your own computer as build agent, as a work around. A reason of failing builds can be that the version of Visual Studio For Mac installed is a bit outdated. We need to wait till they get updated and then we'll be able to use Azure agents again.

Comment: This issue has been raised with MS and you can keep updated here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/363357/error-failed-to-resolve-authenticationservicesaswe.html

Comment: @DomBurf : I found a solution to your question regarding this issue? Do you have any idea about, how to run that script provided in the answer(running the script in Build Pipeline)? I am new to Azure Devops.

Comment: I saw the suggestion about the script (I have subscribed to the issue here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/363357/error-failed-to-resolve-authenticationservicesaswe.html). You will need to add a task to your build pipeline for running a bash script and do this before your build step.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Azure DevOps. I have updated mono version from 5.10 to 5.18.1 and build was succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I downgraded my "Microsoft.Identity.Client" package from 2.3.1 to 2.1.0. My Xamarin.forms project version had to be 3.0.0 for this to work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with `microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory 4.3.0` as well.

That package is also able to save tokens in MSAL-format so perhaps it is also using  `AuthenticationServices.ASWebAuthenticationSession`.

AppCenter won't build at all since it's outdated and Azure DevOps fails with this.

Comment: The solution seems to be to downgrade your version of Xamarin.iOS. I am using 2.1 without any issues. The problem has been raised with MS so hopefully it will get fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Visual Studio 2017, at least 15.8.7, which has support for XCode10, and XCode10 installed on the Mac to get the classes needed to run ASWebAuthenticationSession (ex. AuthenticationServices). If you still have issues, please open an [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues) on the MSAL repo.

Comment: The problem is that the build host on Azure DevOps for iOS doesn't seem to be compatible with the Xamarin.iOS assembly. The issue has now been raised with Microsoft so hopefully they will address it soon.