# Azure DevOps Pipeline Fails When Building Xamarin.iOS project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a Pipeline using YAML in Azure DevOps. I have the following task in my YAML file:

```
- task: XamariniOS@2
  inputs:
    solutionFile: '**/*iOS.csproj'
    configuration: 'Release'
    packageApp: false
    runNugetRestore: false
```

I receive the following errors when the Pipeline runs:

```
ASWebAuthenticationSessionBrowser .cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AuthenticationServices' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/s/AgentConnectMobile/AgentConnectMobile.iOS/AgentConnectMobile.iOS.csproj]
ASWebAuthenticationSessionBrowser .cs(14,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ASWebAuthenticationSession' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/s/AgentConnectMobile/AgentConnectMobile.iOS/AgentConnectMobile.iOS.csproj]
ASWebAuthenticationSessionBrowser .cs(49,72): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/s/AgentConnectMobile/AgentConnectMobile.iOS/AgentConnectMobile.iOS.csproj]
ASWebAuthenticationSessionBrowser .cs(51,51): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ASWebAuthenticationSession' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/s/AgentConnectMobile/AgentConnectMobile.iOS/AgentConnectMobile.iOS.csproj]
```

I'm able to build the iOS project manually successfully in Visual Studio. I have tried removing and re-adding project references but it hasn't seemed to help.

My project is setup like the following:

[image]

Do I need to configure something differently for Azure DevOps?

Comment: The types it is complaining about, where do they come from?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I did some more digging and it looks like this is a known issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896045/error-failed-to-resolve-authenticationservices-aswebauthenticationsession-ref

Comment: To me it simply looks like you didn't restore NuGet packages