# Failed to resolve "AuthenticationServices.IASAuthorizationControllerDelegate" reference from "Xamarin.iOS"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Does anyone have idea of this error? I've searched but haven't find anyone who faced the same issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

> Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "AuthenticationServices.IASAuthorizationControllerDelegate" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065" (MT2002) (SJMC.iOS)

Comment: It seems that you used Azure DevOps .Here is a similar issue which maybe can help you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896045/error-failed-to-resolve-authenticationservices-aswebauthenticationsession-ref?stw=2

Comment: I resolved the issue by upgrading the Xamarin.iOS from **12.14.0.114**  to **12.99.2.40**

Comment: You could post your solution and accept it , which will help more people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by upgrading the Xamarin.iOS from **12.14.0.114** to **12.99.2.40**.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, Please mark your reply as answer. It will help others who have similar issue.